# Transform list output from for loop

Tags: python

```
for line in inputFile: #here is 5 lines
    data = [['Text', 'Count'], [var1, var5]]
    print data
```

**Output:**

```
[['Text', 'Count'], ['Test', 156]]
[['Text', 'Count'], ['Test5', 154]]
[['Text', 'Count'], ['Test6', 156]]
[['Text', 'Count'], ['Test8', 178]]
[['Text', 'Count'], ['Testg', 144]]
```

How can I have output in this way:

```
[['Text', 'Count'], ['Test', 156], ['Test', 156], ['Test', 156],['Test', 156],['Test', 156]]
```

Can I transform my output to this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append each data to a list:

```
L = [['Text', 'Count']]
for line in inputFile:
    L.append([var, var5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Or a simple 1-liner:

```
L = [['Text', 'Count']] + [[var1, var5] for _ in inputFile]
```

Example:

```
>>> inputFile = xrange(10)
>>> var1, var5 = '1', '2'
>>> [['Text', 'Count']] + [[var1, var5] for _ in inputFile]
[['Text', 'Count'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2']]
```

Or using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain([['Text', 'Count']], ([var1, var5] for _ in inputFile)))
```

Comment: This will result in multiple `['Text', 'Count']`

Comment: How so? `[var1, var5]` are different than `['Text', 'Count']` and concatenation is done only once.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread your code. Didn't see that the list comprehension was separate from the concatenation